# Visual Studio Install generating multiple files instead of just setup.exe

Tags: visual-studio, installation, setup-deployment, installshield-le

I had an install project that I have been using and it was generating a setup.exe file... suddenly (I don't remember changing anything) the folder now ends up with many files:

[image: Image of the many files]
It used to end up with just the setup.exe file. (other files were generated during the compilation... but just the setup.exe file remained after compilation was complete.)

Anyone have any idea about what might have changed?

Note: the program files directory has all the usual exe, configs, dll's and such... like this:

[image]

Comment: Also if I try to run setup.exe by itself... doesn't work now... but if I run setup.exe inside a folder with all the other files... it works.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio setup-deployment or Installshield? Above scenario could happen in Setup and deployment when you set installer prerequisite’s option.

Comment: Under the Installation Requirements step I had "Does your application require any software to be installed on the machine?" set to Yes... but no software was selected. Changed this to No and still same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for some reason (brain blip) I started getting the install from this directory:

```
Nexus\NexusInstaller\NexusInstaller\Express\DVD-5\DiskImages\DISK1
```

When in fact I was before (and should be now) getting it from this directory:

```
Nexus\NexusInstaller\NexusInstaller\Express\SingleImage\DiskImages\DISK1
```